# Grub entry to run NixOS?

Tags: grub2, nixos

I'm running Ubuntu and I want to dual boot NixOS. I used the quick install script [on their site](https://nixos.org/download.html), but it didn't make a Grub entry. I have no experience with Grub whatsoever, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command on that page is to install *Nix,* the package manager, not NixOS, the Linux distro. Nix can be run on any Linux distro.

To dual boot you'll have to follow the *NixOS* instructions.

Comment: in my case I did install NixOS, I see the partitions it/I created during install, but no entry on grub

Comment: Indeed OP is right, if you scroll down below "Nix : the package manager" you can find "NixOS : the Linux distribution"